# AWS Glue An error occurred while calling o128.resolveChoice

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have an AWS Glue job that is currently running nightly and scanning about 20 TB worth of raw JSON data and converting it to parquet. I just have the generic Python script that is generated when creating the job. I've run into an issue that is causing the job to fail and resulting in the following error.

> py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o131.resolveChoice

This job has run successfully before without any issues. I made a change and added partition keys and it seems to be failing now after that change. This job takes almost 24 hours to run so coming up with a solution has been a slow process. I've not been able to find any kind of errors that match this one so i'm curious to find out what is happening here. Anybody have any ideas?

Here is the traceback from Cloudwatch

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_2020-09-14-02-00-49.py", line 17, in <module>
    resolvechoice = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = applymapping, choice = "make_struct", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice")
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1600045621100_0001/container_1600045621100_0001_02_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/transforms/transform.py", line 24, in apply
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1600045621100_0001/container_1600045621100_0001_02_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/transforms/resolve_choice.py", line 17, in __call__
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1600045621100_0001/container_1600045621100_0001_02_000001/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/dynamicframe.py", line 420, in resolveChoice
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1600045621100_0001/container_1600045621100_0001_02_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1600045621100_0001/container_1600045621100_0001_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1600045621100_0001/container_1600045621100_0001_02_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 327, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o128.resolveChoice
ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:41623)
```

It seems to be failing on this line.

`resolvechoice = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = applymapping, choice = "make_struct", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice")`

This script is currently working in my pre-production AWS env but not in my production env.